# Angular 6 (TypeScript) - Check if user is new (newly registered) or old user

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im working on a website using Angular that displays information from a user account on a different website. So I have the model typescript class with all the variables related to a user. (type, id, name etc)

I want to check if the user is a new user or an old user. If the user is new, then a popup (terms and agreement popup) would display when the user clicks on a specific tab on my website. But the new user would have to see the popup ONLY ONCE in order to access that tab leading to a page. I have a function for the popup in the app component class.

I`m unable to figure out a way to do something like this. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems like you have to store this data yourself - either as a [session data](https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/use-localstorage-sessionstorage-using-webstorage-angular4/); or if you are using back end with database - you'd store it there.